# bootstrap carousel issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i need to align-center the images and the caption of the bootstrap carrousel

i use php code tho show random images from dataase

here is the i use to keep aspect ratio:

```
<div class="item">';
        while ($resultados = $arte->fetch_assoc()) {
            $title = utf8_encode($resultados['titulo']);
          $id = $resultados['medidas'];
          $tec = utf8_encode($resultados['tecnica']);
          $img = $resultados['imagen'];
          $home .= '  <img src="'.$img.'" style="background-size: cover;background-size: cover;width: auto;height: auto;min-width: 1%;max-height: 600px;max-width: 1000px;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>'.$title.'.</h1>
              <p class="lead">'.$id.'<br> '.$tec.'</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" href="/arte_objeto">Ver m&aacute;s</a>
            </div>
         </div>';
            }
        $home .= '</div>
```

this is the result:

http://prntscr.com/64h3vb

so align the caption too so it shows the image in the center of the carousel

i tried with:

```
background-position: center center;
```

but doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin:0 auto;` on the div's/images you'd like to center.

Use your "inspect element" to find the div's that are pulling to the left and then apply that css.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was `position:absolute;` on `.carousel img {` so i removed it and
also added `margin: 0 auto;` to `.carousel img {`